# Tfidfvectorizer in R for character n-grams

Tags: r

Is there a similar tool as the tfidf vectorizer which converts a collection of raw documents to a matrix of TF-IDF features in a R package?

See [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the text2vec R package. It has TF-IDF capabilities.

Here's the link to the package info: 
[text2vec](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/text2vec.pdf)